# Reorganising an image pixels in a specific order while removing a color

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image that has black colour pixels in it, I want to remove those black pixels and copy the remaining pixels into a new array with different dimensions, I wrote the following code to achieve this

```
import numpy as np

modimg = np.zeros((140,7027,3))
newimg = np.load('newimg.npy')
k = 0 
l = 0
for i in range(400):
    for j in range (2700):
        if np.all(newimg[i][j] != [0., 0., 0.]):
            modimg[k,l,:] = newimg[i,j,:]
            l+=1
            if(l==7027):
                l=0
                k+=1
```

but there are still black pixels present in the `modimg`. I used `np.where(modimg==[0,0,0])` for this

I dont understand what I did wrong in the code.

The original image in `.npy` format is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s7-_FIkt45fwIwLIq4DqqNOSvTOz3_38/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: But I'm adding only those pixel that are not [0, 0, 0], the `if` does that exactly. 400*2700 - the number of black pixels = 140*7027.

Comment: Sounds like you want the size of modimg to be the number of non-black pixels = 400*2700 - 140*7027

Comment: modimg supposed to contain only non-black pixels. I have checked for things in this time and I have found out that k has only incremented till 135, that i weird, I dont understand why its happening.